# Cannot redirect EXE output to file

Tags: powershell, redirect

I have an `exe` program I'm running on `Windows 10` using `PowerShell`. When I run it, I get the following output.

```
> .\Program.exe

Unlocked level 7/10
```

When trying to redirect all output or just stdout to a file, the program stops giving output. For example

```
PS > .\Program.exe > .\out.txt
PS > cat .\out.txt
PS >
```

I did not write the program but what I know is that it was written in C++.
Is there any trick to get the output into a file? I tried running in python and writing output to a file, running in python without fetching the output and redirecting, running from another powershell, and lots of other combinations but they don't seem to be working. Also, when running from Git Bash, I get no output at all.

I was thinking about some checks on the descriptors but I'm not sure since I don't have the source code, only the asm code

Comment: `.\Program.exe > .\out.txt 2>&1`? Also, does *cat* work on other files? What happens if you delete teh output file before? does it get created?

Comment: Read `Get-Help about_redirection` or  view [online](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-5.1) to redirect all possible streams at once use `.\Program.exe > .\out.txt *>&1`

Comment: I've triend using `2>&1` but the file is still empty.. If I only redirect stderr though, I can see the normal program print

Comment: I think they might check somehow if the stdout stream is redirected to prevent bruteforcing the levels or something

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Program.exe is actually generating an error, and not output, first commenter is trying to get you to see that, but not really explaining that part...

(NOTE: You aren't actually using any powershell besides an implied "Invoke-Expression")I think you might be dealing with STDERR vs. STDOUT, when I invoke reg.exe in that fashion from powershell I get no output to the text file.  This is because the text I was seeing was an error message ( Contents of STDERR ) from reg.exe, not the output ( contents of STDOUT ) from the command.  When I passed proper parameters to it ( reg query HKLM\Software\Microsoft > C:\Users\foo\Documents\foo.txt) it wrote the Contents of STDOUT to the text file instead of the screen.

Here is an article that explains it better than I just did:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/110930/redirecting-error-messages-from-command-prompt-stderr-stdout

Comment: I have tried redirecting both stderr and stdout into the file and it's still empty, and then I tried redirecting only stderr and the program started displaying the message about the unlocked level to the console again, that's why I think it's displaying to stdout, tried to figure out by looking into the assembly, they are writing to the console using WriteConsoleA with a handle got from GetStdHandle